# Sort Date array from txt file

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a `.txt` file that store all the information from my form. And I want to have 1 php that display status from the oldest date to today's date.

This is some example of my txt format:

> ID4494 (tab("\t")) 12/02/2008 (tab("\t")) ANJAY
>
> ID4496 (tab("\t")) 14/04/2009 (tab("\t")) SONJA
>
> ID4499 (tab("\t")) 19/03/2014 (tab("\t")) BRIAN

and this is my php file

> $myfilename = "../idfile/digid.txt";
>
> if( file_exists($myfilename) && filesize($myfilename) > 0 ) {
>
> ```
>   $digArray = file($myfilename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
>
>   sort($digArray);
>
>   foreach($digArray as $dig) {
>
>   $oneDigArray = explode("\t", $dig);
>
>   echo "<p>$oneDigArray[0] - $oneDigArray[1] - $oneDigArray[2]</p>";
>
>   }
> ```
>
> } else {
>       echo "
>
> There is no Digital ID.
>
> ";
>      }

I tried to use sort `($digArray[1]);` since the date is array no. 1. But it wont work.

Any suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's [usort](https://www.php.net/usort) function and supply your own comparison function. Like this:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return ($a[1] > $b[1]) ? 1 : -1;  // Ascending order
    // OR 
    return ($a[1] < $b[1]) ? 1 : -1;  // Descending order
}

usort($digArray, "cmp");
```

The above will sort your array by date. Here is a test I did.

**Test:**

```
$digArray = array(
    array(
        "ID4496", "14/04/2009", "SONJA"
    ),
    array(
        "ID4499", "19/03/2014", "BRIAN"
    ),
    array(
        "ID4494", "12/02/2008", "ANJAY"
    ),
);

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return ($a[1] > $b[1]) ? 1 : -1;  // Ascending order
}

usort($digArray, "cmp");

print_r($digArray);
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [0] => ID4494 [1] => 12/02/2008 [2] => ANJAY ) 
    [1] => Array ( [0] => ID4496 [1] => 14/04/2009 [2] => SONJA ) 
    [2] => Array ( [0] => ID4499 [1] => 19/03/2014 [2] => BRIAN ) 
)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you expalin me why is it 1?

Comment: you mean the return 1 and return -1? check the usort php docs, they have full explanations there. Basically 1 means that $a is to be placed before $b in the sorted array, and -1 means the other way around.

Comment: Yeah, Ive read it. Since my date is array no.1 so it is $a[1]. Ive tried to delete my sort function and replace it with the usort function. But still it doesnt work. It changes the order, but im not quite sure it changes based on which order

Comment: Hey @AureliaAmelinda, I don't have your input file, but I did a test with a simulated array, and the output is correct. Check the updated answer to see the test.